# How to return the difference between two arrays containing strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I let's say I have an array like this:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

And then I have another array like this:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

I need my function to compare the two arrays and return "four". For example, I want the function to do nothing when the array does this:

```
["one", "two"]
```

But again, I want the function to return the difference when the array goes back to this:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

I've been playing with array.filter but so far, filter() has done everything *but* what I need it to. I know I could accomplish this with a complicated forEach() but I'd really like to avoid that.

Comment: Do you want (1) all the elements in the second array that are not in the first, (2) all the elements in the first array that are not in the second, or (3) all the elements that appear in one array but not the other?

Comment: I want the function to compare & return the (additions) difference between two arrays.

Comment: [The following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430020/1641941) is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the first half of your question--

```
var a=["one", "two", "three"];
var b=["one", "two", "three", "four"]
var diff=b.filter((word) => !a.includes(word));
console.log(diff);
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Darn it, I was so close but I had my logic backwards. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `Array` prototype:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
```

```js
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

console.log(["test1", "test2","test3","test4","test5","test6"].diff(["test1","test2","test3","test4"]));
```

Comment: Please do not use this answer. Extending the prototype chain of built-in objects is a bad practice and should be done in rare circumstances.